# Operator arithmetic-harmonic mean inequality with operator-valued weights

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, inequalities, operator-theory, matrix-analysis

Let $\Lambda_1,\dots,\Lambda_n$ be strictly positive definite operators in the Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^d$. By an operator arithmetic-harmonic mean inequality with weights $\Lambda_i$ I mean the following:

> For all strictly positive definite operators $X_i$:
>   $$\operatorname{tr} \left[ \sum_i \Lambda_i^{1/2} X_i^{-1} \Lambda_i^{1/2} \right]^{-1} \le \operatorname{tr} \sum_i \Lambda_i X_i$$

What are the necessary and sufficient conditions on $\Lambda_i$ for such an inequality to hold? In particular, is $\sum_i \Lambda_i \ge 1$ necessary or sufficient, as suggested by the scalar weight case $\Lambda_i = \lambda_i$?

**Upd.** As pointed out by Narutaka OZAWA in the comments, $\sum_i \Lambda_i = 1$ implies the stronger operator inequality: $\left[ \sum_i \Lambda_i^{1/2} X_i^{-1} \Lambda_i^{1/2} \right]^{-1} \le \sum_i \Lambda_i^{1/2} X_i \Lambda_i^{1/2}$. It follows that $\sum_i \Lambda_i \ge 1$ is sufficient for the above inequality with traces.

Comment: Even for scalar weights, I don't see why this should be true for all strictly positive definite $X_i$...

Comment: @YemonChoi For scalar weights a stronger statement is known: $\left[ \sum_i \lambda_i X_i^{-1} \right]^{-1} \le \sum_i \lambda_i X_i$ in the operator sense.

Comment: @YemonChoi: And it's actually fairly elementary, since the $n=2$ case $(\lambda X_1^{-1} + (1-\lambda) X_2^{-1})^{-1} \le \lambda X_1 + (1-\lambda) X_2$ is equivalent to the more obvious $(\lambda + (1-\lambda) X_1^{1/2} X_2^{-1} X_1^{1/2})^{-1} \le \lambda + (1-\lambda) X_1^{-1/2} X_2 X_1^{-1/2}$, and general $n$ follows by induction from $n=2$.

Comment: Yes, $\sum\Lambda_i\geq1$ is necessary and sufficient. This follows from one of Jensen's operator inequalities and the fact that $t^{-1}$ is operator convex.  See Theorem 2.1 in http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0204049 where it deals with the case $\sum\Lambda_i=1$. The rest is probably an exercise.

Comment: @AlexanderShamov Thanks -- I missed the idea of thinking of this in terms of convexity

Comment: @NarutakaOZAWA: Thanks a lot, I'll certainly look at that.

Comment: @NarutakaOZAWA: Indeed, the reduction of the $\sum_i \Lambda_i \ge 1$ case to the $\sum_i \Lambda_i = 1$ case is an easy exercise. But I don't see immediately how to prove necessity; in particular, I don't see why the inequality for traces implies operator inequality...

Comment: @AlexanderShamov: In fact, I didn't think of it. I don't see either.